# Проблема со строками (С)

Tags: c, строки

Программа должна найти самое длинное слово из введённой строки и вывести строку без самого длинного слова.

Пока что смог реализовать деление слов через "/", так как просто не понимаю как реализовать это через пробел,и обсчёт максимальной длинны. Осталось перебрать значения и вывести строку без слова с максимальной длинной. Перепробовал разные подходы с массивами но результата не получил поэтому и обращаюсь к вам.

Заранее спасибо!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int max_len = 0;
    char str[240];
    scanf("%s", &str);
    char sep[10] = "/";
    char* istr;
    printf("Line %s\n", str);
    printf("Result \n");
    istr = strtok(str, sep);
    while (istr != NULL)
    {
        if (strlen(istr) > max_len)
        {
            max_len = strlen(istr);
        }
        printf(" \n%s [%d]  ", istr, strlen(istr));
        istr = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }
    printf("\n%d", max_len);

}
```

Comment: А вам нужно разделение слов только по проблему?

Comment: желательно да,но главное реализовать масив слов чтобы потом проводить с ним работы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример обновленного вашего кода с комментариями:

```
void main()
{
    int max_len = 0;
    char str[240];
    scanf("%s", &str);
    char sep[10] = "/";
    char* istr;
    printf("Line %s\n", str);
    printf("Result \n");
    istr = strtok(str, sep);

    //Кол-во слов
    int count = 0;
    //Максимальное кол-во слов
    const int MAX_COUNT = 10;
    //Максимальная длина слова
    const int MAX_SIZE = 40;
    //Массив слов
    char words[MAX_COUNT][MAX_SIZE];
    //Индекс максимально длинного слова
    int max_index = 0;
    while (istr != NULL)
    {
        //Копируем строку istr в массив слов
        strcpy(words[count], istr);
        //Увеличиваем счетчик слов
        ++count;
        if (strlen(istr) > max_len)
        {
            max_len = strlen(istr);
            max_index = count - 1;
        }
        printf(" \n%s [%d]  ", istr, strlen(istr));
        istr = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }
    printf("\n%d", max_len);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое,как освоюсь в кодинге, тоже буду помагать новичкам таким как я сейчас .

Comment: @MarshalStroheim надеюсь :) удачи!